# Taking off a hat cover before praying

Tags: halacha, tefilla, clothing, weather, head

It is clear that one should remove his coat before praying, as one should not rush straight in from the outside to pray. ([Insert source here!](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/50881/edit))

Hats are often sensitive to rain, and special hat-shaped plastic coverings are available in well-stocked Judaica stores.

Would this covering have the same ruling as a coat?

Answer (score 2):

What is clear to you is not so clear to me, but see Mishna Berurah siman 91 #12 Where he states the general rule to wear only clothing you would wear when talking with an important person. He adds that this is dependant on the usual behavior of the time. Another point he mentions there is not to wear the type of gloves that people would wear when traveling. Perhaps this is analogous to your case. If you don't think so, at least we can assume one would not talk to an important person with a glorified garbage bag on their head, so these hat bags would be precluded from the general rule mentioned before.